# Kamino "Multiply" -> lost funds?

Tags: transaction

Today I tried interacting with the Solana ecosystem using Kamino : https://app.kamino.finance/
More accurately, I used the "Multiply" feature. I chose to depisit 0.07 SOL and left the multiplier on x1
I approved the Metamask transactions but the last one failed.
The blockchain explorer shows :

```
FailFinalized (MAX confirmations)  
Program Error: "Instruction #22 Failed"
```

And my wallet now shows that I indeed lost 0.07 SOL
Kamino's tab doesnt show that I have a position in the "Multiply" tab

Thank you very much